# 'Code too large' XML to Java using Jaxb2 and Castor maven plugins

Tags: java, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin, castor

I'm dealing with an older application that we recently updated from Java 8 to Java 11. In one part of the application, I have several XML files (XSDs) that are converted into Java classes using the Jaxb2 Maven plugin. It worked fine with Java 8, but after switching to Java 11, I encountered an error: 'code too large'.

I know that in Java, a method or function can't exceed 65536 bytes in size. But it's puzzling why it worked with Java 8 and not with Java 11. I've spent two weeks on this issue, and I still don't understand why it worked before.

The problem is, I can't split the code into smaller parts because of some limitations. I tried using another plugin called Castor, hoping it would solve the issue, but it also ran into the same problem.

I experimented with different versions of both plugins, but none of them worked with Java 11. The rest of the application runs smoothly with Java 11. It's only when I change the Java version in the Maven plugin that I encounter this compilation error.

Please help to get me out of this issue as I already have spent time alot.
Thanks in advance.

```
        <configuration>
            <release>8</release>  <!-- working fine -->
            <release>11</release>  <!-- problem -->
        <!--<compilerArgs><arg>-J-Xmx512m</arg></compilerArgs>-->
        </configuration>
```

This is the code for plugin Jaxb2 (Dependencies I added and plugin)

## **pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>



<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                    <!--<compilerArgs><arg>-J-Xmx512m</arg></compilerArgs>-->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- The schema directory or xsd files. -->
                    <!--<arguments>
                        <arg>-XautoNameResolution</arg>
                    </arguments>-->
                    <sources>
                        <source>src/main/resources/xsds</source>
                    </sources>
                    <xjbSources>
                        <xjbSource>src/main/resources/xsds/bindings.xjb</xjbSource>
                    </xjbSources>
                    <!-- The package in which the source files will be generated. -->
                    <packageName>com.example.java</packageName>
                    <!-- The working directory to create the generated java source files. -->
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jaxb/</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

**bindings.jxb**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jaxb:bindings
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:jaxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"
        xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
        xmlns:inheritance="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance"
        jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"
        version="3.0">
  <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../xml/afd/code.xsd" node="/xs:schema">

    <jaxb:globalBindings typesafeEnumMemberName="generateName" typesafeEnumMaxMembers="4300">
      <jaxb:serializable uid="1"/>
    </jaxb:globalBindings>
  </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

This is the configuration, I did for **Castor** plugin

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>castor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>


<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <!--<version>3.8.1</version>-->
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                    <!--<compilerArgs><arg>-J-Xmx512m</arg></compilerArgs>-->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- JAXB xjc plugin that invokes the xjc compiler to compile XML schema into Java classes.-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>castor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-main-java-classes</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/xsds</schemaDirectory>
                            <!--<bindingfile>src/main/resources/xsds/binding.xml</bindingfile>-->
                            <packaging>com.example</packaging>
                            <generateImportedSchemas>true</generateImportedSchemas>
                            <descriptors>false</descriptors>
                            <generateMappings>true</generateMappings>
                            <dest>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jaxb/</dest>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I have simpletype in xsd as follow

```
<xs:simpleType name="CODES" >
        <!--<xs:annotation><xs:appinfo>
            <jaxb:globalBindings typesafeEnumMaxMembers="0" />
        </xs:appinfo></xs:annotation>-->
        <xs:restriction base="fm:AN__5">
            <xs:enumeration value="1000"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="1001"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="1002"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="1003"/>
.... up to more than 4000 lines
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: Since you're targeting jaxb4, could you give a try with `org.jvnet.jaxb:jaxb-maven-plugin:4.x` from [https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools](jaxb-tools) ?